# aws rds password change triggers updates to which fields in mysql.user?

Tags: mysql, aws

I'm using AWS RDS with MySql (5.7.mysql_aurora.2.10.2)
Due to internal policy I updated db password via AWS RDS modify DB instance menu.

What I can't grasp is, when I updated pw for dev db instance, both `password_last_changed` and `password_lifetime` fields in `mysql.user` table were updated to the current date, and default lifetime of 90.

However when I updated pw for the prod db instance `password_last_changed` field was correctly updated but `password_lifetime` was updated to `null`.

I've looked into AWS RDS parameter groups settings and found that the `default_password_lifetime` parameter was set to 90 in both dev and prod environments.

Is there any other settings that overrides password lifetime?
Or is there some AWS RDS feature that opts in/out which mysql.user fields are updated?

### Edit

It's not a solution, but as a workaround for select queries I used the global variable `default_password_lifetime` when `mysql.user.password_last_changed` was null.

```
select
  user,
  IFNULL(password_lifetime, @@default_password_lifetime) as password_lifetime
from mysql.user
```

Comment: It is _possible_ that RDS does something different than standard MySQL.